# Tomcat with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am testing out running a tomcat8 on my Mac.  I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre7

MAINTAINER "Sonam Lastname <sonam@mymail.com>"
```

When I run the Docker container with the following command:

```
docker run -d -P sonam/docker-webapp
```

I check for the docker process by

```
docker ps -l
```

and see the port mapped at:

```
0.0.0.0:32769->8080/tcp
```

I am not able to access the tomcat page with localhost:32769 (and even tried to 8080 port).

thanks

-Sonam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker runs in a virtual machine when on Mac. Tomcat will listen to that network interface.

You can run `docker-machine ip <name of your docker machine>` and access it via that IP instead of localhost.

If on boot2docker, it is similar: `boot2docker ip`.